# Parsehub "This Stencil app is disabled for this browser."

Tags: stenciljs, parsehub

I need to scrape some data from transfermarkt.com using parsehub, but when i try to load the website with parse hub I'm only met with:

This Stencil app is disabled for this browser.
Developers:

```
ES5 builds are disabled during development to take advantage of 2x faster build times.
Please see the example below or our config docs if you would like to develop on a browser that does not fully support ES2017 and custom elements.
Note that as of Stencil v2, ES5 builds and polyfills are disabled during production builds. You can enable these in your stencil.config.ts file.
When testing browsers it is recommended to always test in production mode, and ES5 builds should always be enabled during production builds.
This is only an experiment and if it slows down app development then we will revert this and enable ES5 builds during dev.
```

Enabling ES5 builds during development:

npm run dev --es5

For stencil-component-starter, use:

npm start --es5

Enabling full production builds during development:

npm run dev --prod

For stencil-component-starter, use:

npm start --prod

Current Browser's Support:

```
ES Module Imports: false
ES Dynamic Imports: false
Custom Elements: false
Shadow DOM: false
fetch: true
CSS Variables: true
```

Current Browser:

Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.13; rv:65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0

I tried following the steps to enable ES5, but it does not work.

If i go to the website on the standard firefox browser it works like normal, but not in parsehub

Answer (score 0):

That message indicates that the browser [does not support JS modules](https://caniuse.com/es6-module). Looking at parsehub's FAQ they are using Firefox v54 which was released in 2017 and [does not support JS modules](https://caniuse.com/es6-module).

Starting with version 2 [Stencil has changed legacy browser support](https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil/blob/main/BREAKING_CHANGES.md#opt-in-for-ie11-edge-16-18-and-safari-10-builds) to be opt-in.

If you have access to the source code you can add legacy browser support [using the following config](https://stenciljs.com/docs/config-extras):

```
export const config: Config = {
  buildEs5: 'prod',
  extras: {
    cssVarsShim: true,
    __deprecated__dynamicImportShim: true,
    shadowDomShim: true,
    safari10: true,
    scriptDataOpts: true,
    appendChildSlotFix: false,
    cloneNodeFix: false,
    slotChildNodesFix: true,
  }
};
```

The only other options are:

- ask the site to add those config changes and publish a new version
- use a different scraper with a more recent version